# rosmsg wont show message?

Tags: ros, generate-messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I at moment trying to learn about ROS using the guide provided by this page.  Up until now it has been running fine, but for some reason i am not getting the same output as i was supposed to here

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Using_rosmsg

The output i receive is this

> Unable to load msg
> [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot
> locate message [Num]: unknown package
> [beginner_tutorials] on search path
> [{'rosconsole':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosconsole/msg'],
> 'catkin':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/msg'],
> 'angles':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/angles/msg'],
> 'image_view':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/image_view/msg'],
> 'carrot_planner':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/carrot_planner/msg'],
> 'urdf':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/urdf/msg'],
> 'rosgraph':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosgraph/msg'],
> 'rqt_py_console':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_py_console/msg'],
> 'nodelet_topic_tools':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nodelet_topic_tools/msg'],
> 'rqt_graph':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_graph/msg'],
> 'rotate_recovery':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rotate_recovery/msg'],
> 'theora_image_transport':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/theora_image_transport/msg'],
> 'rocon_python_comms':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_python_comms/msg'],
> 'qt_gui':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/qt_gui/msg'],
> 'filters':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/filters/msg'],
> 'ecl_exceptions':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_exceptions/msg'],
> 'navfn':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/navfn/msg'],
> 'dwa_local_planner':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/dwa_local_planner/msg'],
> 'rosgraph_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosgraph_msgs/msg'],
> 'smclib':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/smclib/msg'],
> 'ecl_devices':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_devices/msg'],
> 'rocon_gateway_utils':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_gateway_utils/msg'],
> 'roscpp_serialization':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp_serialization/msg'],
> 'rqt_rviz':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_rviz/msg'],
> 'rosbuild':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbuild/msg'],
> 'qt_gui_cpp':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/qt_gui_cpp/msg'],
> 'rosauth':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosauth/msg'],
> 'tf':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/tf/msg'],
> 'rqt_publisher':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_publisher/msg'],
> 'roslang':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslang/msg'],
> 'geometric_shapes':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/geometric_shapes/msg'],
> 'kobuki_driver':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_driver/msg'],
> 'smach_ros':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/smach_ros/msg'],
> 'genlisp':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/genlisp/msg'],
> 'map_server':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/map_server/msg'],
> 'interactive_markers':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/interactive_markers/msg'],
> 'dynamic_reconfigure':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/dynamic_reconfigure/msg'],
> 'ecl_containers':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_containers/msg'],
> 'diagnostic_aggregator':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/diagnostic_aggregator/msg'],
> 'ecl_license':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_license/msg'],
> 'smart_battery_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/smart_battery_msgs/msg'],
> 'robot_state_publisher':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/robot_state_publisher/msg'],
> 'visualization_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/visualization_msgs/msg'],
> 'diagnostic_updater':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/diagnostic_updater/msg'],
> 'ecl_streams':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_streams/msg'],
> 'resource_retriever':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/resource_retriever/msg'],
> 'rqt_topic':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_topic/msg'],
> 'smach':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/smach/msg'],
> 'ecl_mpl':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_mpl/msg'],
> 'stdr_parser':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stdr_parser/msg'],
> 'ecl_math':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_math/msg'],
> 'rqt_action':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_action/msg'],
> 'rqt_top':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_top/msg'],
> 'rosbridge_server':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbridge_server/msg'],
> 'diagnostic_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/diagnostic_msgs/msg'],
> 'move_base':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/move_base/msg'],
> 'rosboost_cfg':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosboost_cfg/msg'],
> 'genmsg':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/msg'],
> 'xacro':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro/msg'],
> 'turtle_tf2':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtle_tf2/msg'],
> 'rqt_robot_dashboard':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_robot_dashboard/msg'],
> 'pluginlib':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/pluginlib/msg'],
> 'xmlrpcpp':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/xmlrpcpp/msg'],
> 'rqt_service_caller':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_service_caller/msg'],
> 'ar_track_alvar':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ar_track_alvar/msg'],
> 'rqt_msg':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_msg/msg'],
> 'geometry_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/geometry_msgs/msg'],
> 'rosmaster':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosmaster/msg'],
> 'warehouse_ros':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/warehouse_ros/msg'],
> 'yocs_velocity_smoother':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/yocs_velocity_smoother/msg'],
> 'rosnode':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosnode/msg'],
> 'rqt_pose_view':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_pose_view/msg'],
> 'rocon_app_manager':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_app_manager/msg'],
> 'bond':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/bond/msg'],
> 'rocon_apps':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_apps/msg'],
> 'image_geometry':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/image_geometry/msg'],
> 'rocon_app_utilities':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_app_utilities/msg'],
> 'rospack':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rospack/msg'],
> 'rocon_semantic_version':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_semantic_version/msg'],
> 'actionlib_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/actionlib_msgs/msg'],
> 'image_rotate':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/image_rotate/msg'],
> 'rqt_image_view':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_image_view/msg'],
> 'rgbd_launch':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rgbd_launch/msg'],
> 'yocs_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/yocs_msgs/msg'],
> 'roslisp':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslisp/msg'],
> 'rqt_console':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_console/msg'],
> 'joint_state_publisher':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/joint_state_publisher/msg'],
> 'rocon_std_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_std_msgs/msg'],
> 'ecl_sigslots':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_sigslots/msg'],
> 'rviz_plugin_tutorials':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz_plugin_tutorials/msg'],
> 'tf2_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/tf2_msgs/msg'],
> 'python_qt_binding':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/python_qt_binding/msg'],
> 'laser_geometry':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/laser_geometry/msg'],
> 'clear_costmap_recovery':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/clear_costmap_recovery/msg'],
> 'rviz':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/msg'],
> 'rocon_master_info':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_master_info/msg'],
> 'gencpp':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/gencpp/msg'],
> 'rqt_gui_cpp':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_gui_cpp/msg'],
> 'rqt_bag':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_bag/msg'],
> 'rqt_gui':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_gui/msg'],
> 'qt_gui_py_common':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/qt_gui_py_common/msg'],
> 'eigen_conversions':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/eigen_conversions/msg'],
> 'roscpp_traits':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp_traits/msg'],
> 'driver_base':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/driver_base/msg'],
> 'rosout':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosout/msg'],
> 'diagnostic_common_diagnostics':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/diagnostic_common_diagnostics/msg'],
> 'rostopic':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rostopic/msg'],
> 'rospy_tutorials':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rospy_tutorials/msg'],
> 'smach_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/smach_msgs/msg'],
> 'message_generation':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/message_generation/msg'],
> 'camera_calibration':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/camera_calibration/msg'],
> 'kobuki_gazebo':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_gazebo/msg'],
> 'rocon_gateway':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_gateway/msg'],
> 'polled_camera':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/polled_camera/msg'],
> 'gazebo_plugins':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_plugins/msg'],
> 'gazebo_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_msgs/msg'],
> 'ecl_threads':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_threads/msg'],
> 'rostime':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rostime/msg'],
> 'rqt_nav_view':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_nav_view/msg'],
> 'turtlebot_navigation':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/msg'],
> 'urdf_tutorial':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/urdf_tutorial/msg'],
> 'kobuki_auto_docking':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_auto_docking/msg'],
> 'ecl_time_lite':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_time_lite/msg'],
> 'rosservice':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosservice/msg'],
> 'rospy':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rospy/msg'],
> 'kdl_conversions':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kdl_conversions/msg'],
> 'turtle_tf':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtle_tf/msg'],
> 'roscpp_tutorials':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp_tutorials/msg'],
> 'ecl_build':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_build/msg'],
> 'roscpp':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp/msg'],
> 'openni_launch':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/openni_launch/msg'],
> 'turtle_actionlib':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtle_actionlib/msg'],
> 'python_orocos_kdl':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/python_orocos_kdl/msg'],
> 'stage':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stage/msg'],
> 'roslint':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslint/msg'],
> 'depthimage_to_laserscan':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/depthimage_to_laserscan/msg'],
> 'visualization_marker_tutorials':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/visualization_marker_tutorials/msg'],
> 'bondcpp':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/bondcpp/msg'],
> 'rosconsole_bridge':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosconsole_bridge/msg'],
> 'pluginlib_tutorials':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/pluginlib_tutorials/msg'],
> 'gateway_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/gateway_msgs/msg'],
> 'camera_calibration_parsers':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/camera_calibration_parsers/msg'],
> 'rocon_service_pair_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_service_pair_msgs/msg'],
> 'roslz4':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslz4/msg'],
> 'rqt_dep':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_dep/msg'],
> 'ecl_converters':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_converters/msg'],
> 'rocon_python_utils':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_python_utils/msg'],
> 'rosmsg':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosmsg/msg'],
> 'turtlebot_description':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_description/msg'],
> 'actionlib_tutorials':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/actionlib_tutorials/msg'],
> 'turtlesim':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlesim/msg'],
> 'amcl':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/amcl/msg'],
> 'rocon_uri':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_uri/msg'],
> 'rqt_robot_monitor':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_robot_monitor/msg'],
> 'rocon_ebnf':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_ebnf/msg'],
> 'self_test':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/self_test/msg'],
> 'roslib':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslib/msg'],
> 'diagnostic_analysis':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/diagnostic_analysis/msg'],
> 'stereo_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stereo_msgs/msg'],
> 'kobuki_gazebo_plugins':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_gazebo_plugins/msg'],
> 'kobuki_capabilities':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_capabilities/msg'],
> 'pcl_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/pcl_msgs/msg'],
> 'trajectory_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/trajectory_msgs/msg'],
> 'create_driver':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/create_driver/msg'],
> 'move_base_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/move_base_msgs/msg'],
> 'capabilities':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/capabilities/msg'],
> 'turtlebot_gazebo':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/msg'],
> 'laser_assembler':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/laser_assembler/msg'],
> 'ecl_errors':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_errors/msg'],
> 'pcl_conversions':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/pcl_conversions/msg'],
> 'fake_localization':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/fake_localization/msg'],
> 'rviz_python_tutorial':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz_python_tutorial/msg'],
> 'robot_pose_publisher':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/robot_pose_publisher/msg'],
> 'tf2':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/tf2/msg'],
> 'rqt_runtime_monitor':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_runtime_monitor/msg'],
> 'ecl_eigen':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_eigen/msg'],
> 'rosbash':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbash/msg'],
> 'rqt_reconfigure':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_reconfigure/msg'],
> 'rqt_bag_plugins':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_bag_plugins/msg'],
> 'bfl':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/bfl/msg'],
> 'rqt_launch':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_launch/msg'],
> 'rocon_python_redis':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_python_redis/msg'],
> 'yocs_controllers':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/yocs_controllers/msg'],
> 'rqt_plot':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_plot/msg'],
> 'topic_tools':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/topic_tools/msg'],
> 'rostest':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rostest/msg'],
> 'ecl_time':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_time/msg'],
> 'tf_conversions':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/tf_conversions/msg'],
> 'control_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/control_msgs/msg'],
> 'cpp_common':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/cpp_common/msg'],
> 'nodelet':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nodelet/msg'],
> 'nodelet_tutorial_math':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nodelet_tutorial_math/msg'],
> 'rqt_robot_steering':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_robot_steering/msg'],
> 'kobuki_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_msgs/msg'],
> 'genpy':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/genpy/msg'],
> 'tf2_geometry_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/tf2_geometry_msgs/msg'],
> 'ar_track_alvar_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ar_track_alvar_msgs/msg'],
> 'compressed_image_transport':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/compressed_image_transport/msg'],
> 'rqt_shell':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_shell/msg'],
> 'zeroconf_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/zeroconf_msgs/msg'],
> 'roscreate':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscreate/msg'],
> 'image_transport':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/image_transport/msg'],
> 'stdr_resources':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stdr_resources/msg'],
> 'ecl_mobile_robot':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_mobile_robot/msg'],
> 'rocon_app_manager_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_app_manager_msgs/msg'],
> 'rocon_python_wifi':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_python_wifi/msg'],
> 'qt_dotgraph':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/qt_dotgraph/msg'],
> 'stdr_gui':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stdr_gui/msg'],
> 'ecl_geometry':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_geometry/msg'],
> 'cv_bridge':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/cv_bridge/msg'],
> 'gazebo_ros':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_ros/msg'],
> 'rosbag_storage':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbag_storage/msg'],
> 'ecl_utilities':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_utilities/msg'],
> 'rocon_hub':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_hub/msg'],
> 'roswtf':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roswtf/msg'],
> 'std_srvs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/std_srvs/msg'],
> 'eigen_stl_containers':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/eigen_stl_containers/msg'],
> 'rospy_message_converter':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rospy_message_converter/msg'],
> 'ecl_concepts':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_concepts/msg'],
> 'global_planner':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/global_planner/msg'],
> 'mk':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/mk/msg'],
> 'octomap':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/octomap/msg'],
> 'rocon_hub_client':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_hub_client/msg'],
> 'stage_ros':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stage_ros/msg'],
> 'ecl_linear_algebra':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_linear_algebra/msg'],
> 'stereo_image_proc':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stereo_image_proc/msg'],
> 'joy':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/joy/msg'],
> 'bondpy':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/bondpy/msg'],
> 'collada_urdf':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/collada_urdf/msg'],
> 'stdr_robot':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stdr_robot/msg'],
> 'camera_info_manager':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/camera_info_manager/msg'],
> 'kobuki_description':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_description/msg'],
> 'stdr_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stdr_msgs/msg'],
> 'rqt_web':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_web/msg'],
> 'ecl_formatters':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_formatters/msg'],
> 'class_loader':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/class_loader/msg'],
> 'tf2_py':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/tf2_py/msg'],
> 'shape_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/shape_msgs/msg'],
> 'kobuki_ftdi':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_ftdi/msg'],
> 'cmake_modules':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/cmake_modules/msg'],
> 'nav_core':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nav_core/msg'],
> 'uuid_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/uuid_msgs/msg'],
> 'create_node':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/create_node/msg'],
> 'move_slow_and_clear':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/move_slow_and_clear/msg'],
> 'rocon_console':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_console/msg'],
> 'robot_pose_ekf':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/robot_pose_ekf/msg'],
> 'create_description':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/create_description/msg'],
> 'nav_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/nav_msgs/msg'],
> 'rosmake':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosmake/msg'],
> 'image_proc':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/image_proc/msg'],
> 'costmap_2d':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/costmap_2d/msg'],
> 'ecl_type_traits':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_type_traits/msg'],
> 'kobuki_dock_drive':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_dock_drive/msg'],
> 'zeroconf_avahi':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/zeroconf_avahi/msg'],
> 'depth_image_proc':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/depth_image_proc/msg'],
> 'actionlib':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/actionlib/msg'],
> 'laser_filters':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/laser_filters/msg'],
> 'kobuki_safety_controller':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_safety_controller/msg'],
> 'kobuki_node':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_node/msg'],
> 'rosparam':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosparam/msg'],
> 'rosunit':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosunit/msg'],
> 'rosclean':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosclean/msg'],
> 'std_capabilities':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/std_capabilities/msg'],
> 'tf2_ros':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/tf2_ros/msg'],
> 'turtlebot_bringup':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/msg'],
> 'librviz_tutorial':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/librviz_tutorial/msg'],
> 'rqt_moveit':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_moveit/msg'],
> 'pcl_ros':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/pcl_ros/msg'],
> 'base_local_planner':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/base_local_planner/msg'],
> 'interactive_marker_tutorials':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/interactive_marker_tutorials/msg'],
> 'shape_tools':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/shape_tools/msg'],
> 'message_runtime':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/message_runtime/msg'],
> 'stdr_server':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/stdr_server/msg'],
> 'rqt_py_common':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_py_common/msg'],
> 'message_filters':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/message_filters/msg'],
> 'std_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/std_msgs/msg'],
> 'kobuki_bumper2pc':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_bumper2pc/msg'],
> 'gmapping':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/gmapping/msg'],
> 'yocs_cmd_vel_mux':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/yocs_cmd_vel_mux/msg'],
> 'rosbridge_library':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbridge_library/msg'],
> 'random_numbers':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/random_numbers/msg'],
> 'rosapi':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosapi/msg'],
> 'rqt_srv':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_srv/msg'],
> 'rqt_gui_py':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_gui_py/msg'],
> 'voxel_grid':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/voxel_grid/msg'],
> 'map_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/map_msgs/msg'],
> 'rocon_icons':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rocon_icons/msg'],
> 'roslaunch':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/roslaunch/msg'],
> 'compressed_depth_image_transport':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/compressed_depth_image_transport/msg'],
> 'rqt_tf_tree':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_tf_tree/msg'],
> 'openni_camera':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/openni_camera/msg'],
> 'collada_parser':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/collada_parser/msg'],
> 'rqt_logger_level':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rqt_logger_level/msg'],
> 'kobuki_random_walker':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_random_walker/msg'],
> 'ecl_command_line':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_command_line/msg'],
> 'openslam_gmapping':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/openslam_gmapping/msg'],
> 'kdl_parser':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kdl_parser/msg'],
> 'rosbag_migration_rule':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbag_migration_rule/msg'],
> 'media_export':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/media_export/msg'],
> 'laptop_battery_monitor':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/laptop_battery_monitor/msg'],
> 'kobuki_keyop':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_keyop/msg'],
> 'urdf_parser_plugin':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/urdf_parser_plugin/msg'],
> 'ecl_config':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/ecl_config/msg'],
> 'sensor_msgs':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/sensor_msgs/msg'],
> 'orocos_kdl':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/orocos_kdl/msg'],
> 'rosbag':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbag/msg'],
> 'kobuki_rapps':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/kobuki_rapps/msg'],
> 'unique_id':
> ['/opt/ros/indigo/share/unique_id/msg']}]

eventhough an ls shows that the file exist... ??? i am confused..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202129/rosmsg---wont-show-message??/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the ROS tools can't find your beginner_tutorials package.

- You should make sure that you've sourced the devel/setup.bash in your workspace
- You should make sure that your package is named beginner_tutorials
- You can check that ROS can find your package with `rospack find beginner_tutorials`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-01-30**:
It will not `rospack find` the package/directory eventhoug it inside of it.
i tried `source devel/setup.bash` it just say that such file doesn't exist.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-02**:
Is your package in a catkin workspace? The devel folder should be in the top level of your workspace, and the setup.bash should be generated when you run catkin_make.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-03**:
workspace is made by using catkin_init_workspace, and catkin_make.  I have been getting the right output from the previous sections of the tutorials... But this  section doesn't seem to be correct..

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-03**:
i don't know if it help but here is my workspace..
My workspace is given here.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dud6uwhmmxf93cf/link.txt?dl=0

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-03**:
You have two copies of the beginner_tutorials package in your workspace; one at the top level (wrong) and one inside the src folder (right). ROS cannot find any packages that exist outside of the src folder in your workspace.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-03**:
exactly...  Problem fixed.

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-04-01**:
Please explain what was the cause of the problem in detail. Your dropbox is not available anymore